# Eigen Decomposition Check

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am following the wiki entry on [eigen dicomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix) with the following matrix:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1  \\
  1 & 0  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

I wish to find a diagonalizing matrix T.S.

$$T^{-1}AT=\Lambda$$
$$AT=T\Lambda$$
where,
$$\Lambda = \begin{pmatrix}
  x & 0  \\
  0 & y  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$T = \begin{pmatrix}
  a & b  \\
  c & d  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

I am following with the wiki:
$$A\begin{pmatrix}a \\c \\\end{pmatrix}=x\begin{pmatrix}a \\c \\\end{pmatrix}$$
$$A\begin{pmatrix}b \\d \\\end{pmatrix}=y\begin{pmatrix}b \\d \\\end{pmatrix}$$

and the eigenvalues are:
$$\left|A-I\lambda\right| = \left|\begin{pmatrix}-\lambda & 1  \\1 & -\lambda  \\\end{pmatrix}\right|=(\lambda^2-1)=(\lambda-1)(\lambda+1)$$
Hence, $\lambda_{1,2}=\pm 1$

Now I am finding the eigenvectors with:

$$A\begin{pmatrix}a \\c \\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0 \\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\c \\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}c \\a \\\end{pmatrix}=1\begin{pmatrix}a \\c \\\end{pmatrix}$$

Hence, $a=c$. And,
$$A\begin{pmatrix}b \\d \\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0 \\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}b\\d \\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}d \\b \\\end{pmatrix}=-1\begin{pmatrix}b \\d \\\end{pmatrix}$$

Hence, $b=-d$.

So I take $T$ to be:

$$T = \begin{pmatrix}
  a & b  \\
  a & -b  \\
 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1  \\
  1 & -1  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

with:
$$T^{-1} = \frac{1}{det(T)}\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & -1  \\
  -1 & -1  \\
 \end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{-1-1}\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & -1  \\
  -1 & -1  \\
 \end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{-2}\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & -1  \\
  -1 & -1  \\
 \end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & 1  \\
  1 & 1  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

Now, when I try to calculate $T^{-1}AT$ I get:
$$\Lambda =\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & 1  \\
  1 & 1  \\
 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1  \\
  1 & 0  \\
 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1  \\
  1 & -1  \\
 \end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & -1  \\
  1 & 1  \\
 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1  \\
  1 & -1  \\
 \end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -2  \\
  2 & 0  \\
 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -1  \\
  1 & 0  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

Where have I gone wrong here?

Comment: Just the last step -- you've calculated $T^{-1}AT$ incorrectly.

Comment: $$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1& 1\\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: If you're confused by @FlorisClaassens comment above, so was I. I've made the computations and concluded that it's not relevant to what the OP did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a good check you can compute $TT^{-1}$, and you'll find you don't get the identity matrix. So the mistake must be in your computation of $T^{-1}$.

It looks to me like you've set it up wrong. Seems you're trying to use the formula $$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\frac1{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{pmatrix}$$ but you've mixed up some of the terms.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct except that you forgot to switch the elements on the diagonal of $T$ when finding its inverse.